# date calculate[add or subtract days]

Tags: python, python-3.7

hay guys i need to write a program that i give a date and then i give numbers of days and then i get a new date ( the numbers of days can be + or - ). i will be happy if someone help me. (about the first and second line , i just need them in the output)

```
specific_date =input('Enter a date:')
numofdays=input("Enter number of days:")
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
specific_date = datetime(day/month/year)
new_date = specific_date + timedelta(numofdays)

if (year % 400 == 0):
    leap_year = True
elif (year % 100 == 0):
    leap_year = False
elif (year % 4 == 0):
    leap_year = True
else:
    leap_year = False

month=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12']
if month in (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12):
    day in [1,31]
elif month == 2:
    if leap_year:
        day in[1,29]
    else:
        day in[1,28]
        if month in (4,6,9,11):
            day in [1,30]
```

Comment: I don't see a question here.  A cursory glance at your code looks good.

Comment: What are all those `day in`s supposed to do?

Comment: FYI, `day in [1,30]` will return a boolean and discard it if used as a single statement. Essentially, it's a no-op in this case. You could as well write just `5` or just `"hello"` instead

Comment: So you have a date and a delta_t in [days] and you want to calculate a new date? In principle, if you have a date as a datetime object and a datetime timedelta, `datetime` will handle the rest for you (leap years and so on).

Comment: i need to write a code just with loops and if/else , i can't use the date time